# dyld: Library not loaded: QtWidgets

Tags: ros, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran `run demo_nodes_cpp talker`  successfully but now I have troubles with this. I searched where `QtWidgets` is and it is at `/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/A/QtWidgets`

```
username@Ts-Mac ~ % ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Documents/ROS/ros2-osx/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node
  Reason: image not found
```

Would you tell me how to solve please?

I am using: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)/ macOS Big Sur Version11.4/ ros2-foxy-20201211-macos-amd64.tar.bz2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382174/dyld:-library-not-loaded:-qtwidgets/) by [anonymous76965](https://answers.ros.org/users/76965/anonymous76965/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) on 2021-12-28**:
I am running into the same problem with ROS2 Foxy on macOS Monterrey. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, you have to downgrade Qt to version 5 and change the references to the library to that version. To do that:

1. Install Qt version 5:

> brew unlink qt
> brew install qt@5
> brew link --force qt@5

2. Change the references to the Qt libraries within the `turtlesim` executable by doing the following:

   `install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets /usr/local/opt/qt@5/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets /path/to/turtlesim_node`

And repeat that command with by replacing `QtWidgets` with `QtGui` and `QtCore`. See the thread about this here: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1107#issuecomment-1002573856

---

Originally posted by [wgrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/91889/wgrand/) with karma: 26 on 2021-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1